# How to generate a callable predicate that return the opposite of original predicate in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In google.api_core.retry package, there is a function called `if_exception_type()`
this function creates a predicate to check if the exception is of a given type.
below is its [source code](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/_modules/google/api_core/retry.html#if_exception_type).

```py
def if_exception_type(*exception_types):
    """Creates a predicate to check if the exception is of a given type.

    Args:
        exception_types (Sequence[:func:`type`]): The exception types to check
            for.

    Returns:
        Callable[Exception]: A predicate that returns True if the provided
            exception is of the given type(s).
    """

    def if_exception_type_predicate(exception):
        """Bound predicate for checking an exception type."""
        return isinstance(exception, exception_types)

    return if_exception_type_predicate
```

---

Now, I am working with Google BigQuery Reservation API, and wanted to delete a BQ reservation if it exists.
I have some code like this.

```py
from google.cloud.bigquery_reservation_v1 \
    import ReservationServiceClient, CapacityCommitment, Reservation, Assignment
from google.api_core.retry import Retry, if_exception_type
from google.api_core import exceptions as gcp_exceptions

bq_resrv_api = ReservationServiceClient()
bq_resrv_api_retry = Retry(deadline=120,
                            predicate=if_exception_type_not(gcp_exceptions.NotFound),
                            maximum=3)

try:
    bq_resrv_api.delete_reservation(
        name=reservation_registry["reservation_id"],
        retry=bq_resrv_api_retry
    )
    print("BQ slot reservation deleted: {}".format(reservation_registry["reservation_id"]))
except gcp_exceptions.NotFound:
    print("BQ slot reservation not found, skip deletion: {}".format(reservation_registry["reservation_id"]))
```

How could I create a function `if_exception_type_not()` which creates a predicate to check if the exception is **not** of a given type? ( the opposite of `if_exception_type()` )

I came up with an answer (which I will post below), however, I think there shall be a better / more elegant / more generic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a wrapper for the `not` function, and call it `invert` or similar.

We want to end up with a function with signature `exception -> bool`.

We already have access to a function `exception -> bool`, so we just need to chain it with a function that can take a function and return a new function with inverted results: `(exception -> bool) -> (exception -> bool)`.  This is just a decorator.

```
from functools import wraps

def invert(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return not func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then you can pass

```
predicate=invert(if_exception_type(gcp_exceptions.NotFound))
```

Comment: thank you, Cireo. you meant this?```predicate=invert(if_exception_type(gcp_exceptions.NotFound))
```

Comment: yes, thanks!  I copy-pasted from your question and forgot to remove

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to implement the if_exception_type_not() function.

```py
def if_exception_type_not(*exception_types):
    # get the predicate func from if_exception_type
    if_exception_type_predicate = if_exception_type(*exception_types)
    # define a new predicate func that returns the opposite
    def if_exception_type_predicate_not(exception):
        return not if_exception_type_predicate(exception)
    # return the new predicate func
    return if_exception_type_predicate_not
```

However, as you could see, it is very specific to `if_exception_type()`. I think there must be a more generic way to do this.